# How do i make a auto response in my form?

Tags: php

I'd create this form using PhpMailer.
It works very well, but i dont know how i put a auto response.

My code is:

```
 require_once("autenvio/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

 $mail = new PHPMailer();

 $mail->IsSMTP(); 
 $mail->Host = "smtp.mysite.com.br"; 
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = false; 
 $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
 $mail->Username = 'contact@mysite.com.br'; 
 $mail->Password = '*******';  

 $mail->Sender = "contact@mysite.com.br"; 
 $mail->From = "contact@mysite.com.br"; 
 $mail->FromName = "contact@mysite.com.br"; 

 $mail->AddAddress('contact@mysite.com.br', 'Nome - Recebe1'); 
 //$mail->AddAddress('recebe2@dominio.com.br'); 
 //$mail->AddCC('copia@dominio.net'); 
 //$mail->AddBCC('copiaoculta@dominio.info'); 

 $mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
 $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

 $mail->Subject  = "Inscrição 1"; // Assunto da mensagem
 $mail->Body .= "".$_POST['nome'].";".$_POST['cpf'].";".$_POST['nascimento'].";".$_POST['celular'].";".$_POST['email'].";".$_POST['cargo'].";".$_POST['empresa'].";".$_POST['endereco'].";".$_POST['numero'].";".$_POST['complemento'].";".$_POST['cidade'].";".$_POST['estado'].";".$_POST['cep'].";".$_POST['setordaempresa'].";".$_POST['eassociado'].";".$_POST['tickets'].";".$_POST['comosoube'].";".$_POST['cracha'].";".$_POST['empresacracha'].";".$_POST['message']."
"; 

 $enviado = $mail->Send();

 $mail->ClearAllRecipients();

$urls = array(
             'R$750,00 ancord com dados'=>'https://www.mysite.com.br/inscricao/redirect/confirmacaoaa1.html',
             'R$900,00 ancord sem dados'=>'https://www.mysite.com.br/inscricao/redirect/confirmacaoaa2.html',
             'R$940,00 apoiadora com dados'=>'https://www.mysite.com.br/inscricao/redirect/confirmacaoaea1.html',
             'R$1.125,00 apoiadora sem dados'=>'https://www.mysite.com.br/inscricao/redirect/confirmacaoaea2.html',
             'R$1.175,00 nao associdado com dados'=>'https://www.mysite.com.br/inscricao/redirect/confirmacaona1.html',
             'R$1.410,00 nao associado sem dados'=>'https://www.mysite.com.br/inscricao/redirect/confirmacaona2.html');
if (!empty($_REQUEST['tickets'])) {
  $ticket = $_REQUEST['tickets'];
  $qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $qs = ($qs != '') ? '?' . $qs : "";
  $url = $urls[$ticket] . $qs;
  header("location: $url");
  }
```

What should i do to put a auto response like: "Thanks for subscribe! We are very glad..."

Comment: You mean sending another email to the person who filled in your form?

Comment: @ChinLeung yes!!